# Worksheet for class

Tags: calculus

Let f(x) be a function. Define D(f(x)) = lim h→0 (f(x + h) − f(x))/h

Let a be any real number. Show that if f(x)=a for all x ,
then D(f(x))=0 . In other words, when f(x) is identically constant,
the limit is always zero.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Plug in $f(x)=a$ into the formula

Comment: Tyma - so would the simple answer just be (a+h)-a/h? Then h = 0?

Comment: Joanie: Why $(a+h)$?